# Regex to keep characters that are touching (no spaces) a regex match

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this regex to match version numbers, basically digits and dots touching. Note that these software versions I'm wanting to isolate are not proper semver versions and have a lot of exception and quirks

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(?:\.\d+)+/', $version, $matches)) { 
    return $matches[0]; //returning the first match 
}
```

It works great for keeping the digits and dots, but I want to also keep any character that isn't a dot or digit but touches the version number before or after

For example I'd like these versions to be returned whole:

```
2021.02.21A
1.08bh1
v0.1.2.4
1.14-2018
```

Any help would be much appreciated : ) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `\S*` to each end of your regex; this will match any non-space character that is immediately adjacent to something which matches the version number part of the regex. For example:

```php
$versions = [
    'version 2021.02.21A',
    '1.08bh1 and others',
    'from v0.1.2.4 onward',
    'version 1.14-2018 only'
];

foreach ($versions as $version) {
    preg_match('/\S*\d+(?:\.\d+)+\S*/', $version, $matches);
    echo "$matches[0]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2021.02.21A
1.08bh1
v0.1.2.4
1.14-2018
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4sK30)